# Adding custom fields to Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have defined my model with various fields.
Some of these are custom fields, which I am using to validate credit card data, using the fields.py file of my app. Source is [here](https://github.com/bryanchow/django-creditcard-fields).

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    card_name = models.CharField()
    card_number = CreditCardField(required=True)
    security_code = VerificationValueField(required=True)
    expiry_date = ExpiryDateField(required=True)
```

I have defined a ModelForm in my forms.py file.

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = "__all__"
```

And I've added the form to my admin.py file.

```
class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TransactionForm

    def get_fieldsets(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            (None, {
                'fields': ('card_name', 'card_number'),
            }),
        )
admin.site.register(Transaction, TransactionAdmin)
```

However, the custom fields don't seem to be showing in the administration panel. Having done a ton of research, I found [this](https://www.silviogutierrez.com/blog/django-dynamic-admin-forms/), which would seem to be the solution, except it doesn't work. I've tried all sorts of over things including adding a fields tuple with the missing fields to get it to work, but no dice. And yes I've done plenty of searching.

The error I get when following the solution in the last link is this:

`Unknown field(s) (card_number) specified for Transaction. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class TransactionAdmin.`

Running Django 1.7.4, Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your model / admin / form like this

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    card_name = models.CharField()
    card_number = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField()
    card_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    card_number = CreditCardField(required=True)
    expiry_date = ExpiryDateField(required=True)
    card_code = VerificationValueField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = "__all__"
```

```
class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TransactionForm

admin.site.register(Transaction, TransactionAdmin)
```

**UPDATE:**

`CreditCardField` is a Form field, not a model field. See its usage in the same link that you have posted.

Those fields will come in the form.

Comment: It's funny because I actually did that before, but I wasn't sure if it was considered good practice to split / repeat the different fields of a model and form into two separate files. But I guess it makes sense considering that the django-creditcard-fields are actually form fields and not model fields.

Thanks for the clarification. Just one more question, will any properties I specify in the models be inherited by the form fields as well?

Comment: Yes, as we haven't defined `card_name` in the form but it will show up. We aren't splitting the fields into the form / model, we are defining the validation for existing fields (card number, expiry, card code) in the form.