# How to make custom input fields in django admin not related to the model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Info from input fields i would be to use inside `save_model` method.
I know how to make read only fields.

```
class InboiceDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = CarProductDataForm

    readonly_fields = ('car_brand', 'car_number', 'year_of_manufacture')

    def car_brand(self, obj):
        person_id = get_request().user.person.id
        car = CarProductData.objects.get(product__customer__person_id=person_id)
        return car.car_brand
```

but i want to add fields for input info.

Comment: Try with this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056477/adding-custom-fields-to-django-admin